# How to decode a json data array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

The json data object below is what's returned from a custom Google search API request. I need to extract each of the "url" elements and place them into an array (using PHP).

myArray = {url1, url2, url3, etc...}

How?

```
data =  '{
"responseData": 
{
    "results":
    [
        {
            //etc
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: PHP, I've edited the question to add that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try "json decode php" in Google ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I right that you have JSON string? Use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) to decode it. After that you can use

```
 array_map(function($x){
     return $x->url;
 },$var->responceData->results);
```

(Requires PHP 5.3 for anonymous function, you can use no anonymous ones if use PHP5.2 or older)

For later versions:

```
function smth($x){
    return $x->url;
}
array_map('smth',$var->responceData->results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` to get an array corresponding to your JSON and then analyze it like you would do for  a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$myObject=json_decode($myJSONstring);
```

Here's the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Then do:

```
$urlArray=array();
foreach($myObject->responseData->results as $myResult) {
    foreach($myResult as $myAttribute => $myValue) {
        $urlArray[] = $myValue;
    }
}
```

$urlArray will be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)